# Dynamically assign a click event to every single button located in a grid cell

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

I've been woring on a Xamarin Forms application (UWP).

I'd like to assign a click event to every single cell located inside a grid dynamically.
The goal is to handle righ mouse clicks for every single button so that
the background color of the relevant button changes.
I've seen solutions connected to ObservableCollection.
However, I'm curious whether it is possible to carry out
the mentioned task without utilizing it.

I mean to write a single event method definition which is capable of
sensing the very button the user clicks on.

Here's how I imagine the code layout (#c):

```
for (int i = 0; i < _lattice.Size; i++) //Add rows
            {
                ColumnDefinition columna = new ColumnDefinition();

                columna.Width = new GridLength(25);
                
                _gamePage._gameGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columna);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < _lattice.Size; i++) //Add columns
            {
                RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
                row.Height = new GridLength(25);
                _gamePage._gameGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(row);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < _lattice.Size; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < _lattice.Size; j++)
                {
                    Button but = new Button();

                    
                    but.BorderColor = Color.LightGray;
                    but.BorderWidth = 2;
                    but.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
                    but.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
                    
                    //Assigning click event
                    but.Clicked += ButtonClicEvent;

                    _lattice.ButtonLattice[j * _lattice.Size + i] = but;
                    Grid.SetRow(but, i);
                    Grid.SetColumn(but, j);
                    GamePage._gameGrid.Children.Add(but); //Add the desired button to the grid 
                }
            }
```

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  Have you tried it?  Is there some specific problem you're having with this code?

Comment: Specific issue: inside the event method how to identify the button which is being clicked on?

Comment: **every** C# event handler has a `sender` parameter that is a reference to the object that fired the event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every C# event handler has a sender parameter that is a reference to the object that fired the event

```
protected void ButtonClicEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var btn = (Button)sender;

  // btn is a reference to the button that fired the event
  btn.BackgroundColor = Color.Orange;
}
```